# Use proof irrelevance in cast

Tags: coq, dependent-type, equality, irrelevance

I'm working using cast in [Coq.Vectors](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Vectors.VectorEq.html). When trying to rewrite with proofs, I'd like to use the fact of [proof irrelevance (Coq.Logic.Eqdep_dec)](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.Eqdep_dec.html), preferably automatically. I.e., when I have a lemma containing a cast with an explicit proof, I want to able to rewrite a statement that is equivalent. Is there someway I could either do this manually or automatically?

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible, but not so easy to build infrastructure to do.

I'd suggest you have a look at MathComp's `subType` class, and how it organizes the set of irrelevant proofs.

To work with `Vector.t` effectively though, you'll need to master `ssreflect` `rewrite`, IMHO regular `rewrite` is not powerful enough as to properly be used as you'll have to perform complex subterm selection.

Note that we don't recommend using `Vector.t` anymore, see this PR for more info upstream: https://github.com/coq/coq/pull/18032